# unable to find com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.setResourcesContextPath(String)

Tags: groovy, jersey, guice, grizzly

I trying to expose some groovy service with jersey and girzzly. but i got a wierd error when i'm launching my servlet container.
Here is the snippet which lauch it:

```
ServletAdapter adapter = new ServletAdapter();
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new GmediaModule());

GuiceContainer container = new GuiceContainer(injector);
adapter.setServletInstance(container);
adapter.setContextPath("gmedia")

adapter.addInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages",
                   "gmedia.api.music.resources");

threadSelector = GrizzlyServerFactory.create(BASE_URI, adapter);
```

Here is the error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.setResourcesContextPath(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

The error occurs at the grizzlyServeletFactory.create. I'm wordering why this error occurs since this metod exist on this oject?

Comment: on the same class it look like this  static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:6060/";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry i was an idiot. Here is what i'm using now
     GrizzlyWebServer ws = new GrizzlyWebServer(9999);

```
ServletAdapter adapter = new ServletAdapter();
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new GmediaModule());

GuiceContainer container = new GuiceContainer(injector);
adapter.setServletInstance(container);


adapter.addInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages",
                   "gmedia.api.music.resources");

ws.addGrizzlyAdapter(adapter);
ws.start()
```

Comment: Why does this solve your problem? I have a similar error using JerseyTest

Comment: OOps sorry, it miss somthing. There variable ws is a  GrizzlyWebServer.   ws = new GrizzlyWebServer(SERVER_PORT);
Previously I wasn't using this type at all. I think this is where my error belong.